# Migrate single repository from one Atlassian stash server to another server and maintain all data

Tags: git, bitbucket-server

I'm looking to move a git remote from one stash server to another.  I can use git to clone and have seen many other recommendations using --mirror and other git commands to insure all branches and commits are copied and this does work for the most important parts.

What's missing is the pull request history.  Is there anyway to extract this from one stash server and import it to another?

Comment: This seems to be a request to do the same from github https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/STASH-4554 I am going from one stash server to another though, hoping I can do it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm a product manager for Stash. Unfortunately the same answer applies for moving between Stash instances at the moment. This is something we'd like to add, but there are no specific plans at present to do so.

Comment: It would be great if you guys put this in documentation. Extremely annoying to find things that are impossible within the Atlassian tool set that sound perfectly reasonable.

Comment: Rog, Is there any news about this now?